# How to add multipl object in blocking queue?

Tags: java, android

```
BlockingQueue<ServiceSync>bq=new LinkedBlockingDeque<ServiceSync>();

ServiceSync s=new ServiceSync();
s.setService(OperationsConst.CODE, commonUtil.DOWNLOAD, true,null );    
bq.add(s);
//s=new ServiceSync();
s.setService(OperationsConst.LOGIN, commonUtil.DOWNLOAD, true,null );           
bq.add(s);          
tmp=new TempThread(bq, context);
tmp.setBlockingQueue(bq);
```

Here, I added 2 objects but every time, only the second object is added in the queue.

Comment: Uncomment `//s=new ServiceSync();`. Why did you comment it in the first place?

Comment: because every time create new object . it take memory so i blocked that line

Comment: so how do you want to have a "second object" if you are not creating it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are adding `s` to the queue, change the value you added and add it second time. So you end up with a queue that has the same object there twice. Either uncomment the `s=new ServiceSync()`, or (better) create a new variable of type `ServiceSync` and add it to the queue.

Comment: no need to create a new variable: its waste of time, he needs to create just a new object

Comment: Creating a variable a waste of time? Assigning new object to the same variable is not the cleanest of the codes. Yes, I agree he needs to create a new object, how he will do it is up to him.

Comment: waste of your time and waste of memory heap, really

Comment: Why waste of time, from JVM standpoint it is no different. As for the heap, yes it might use more (but it really depends on the type of memory management), but developers shouldn't worry about that, its a job of garbage collector. If he exists this method after creating this second object it is no way different if he does it to the old variable or to the new one. If you are developing real time systems then yes you can worry about that and sacrifice readability for performance.

Comment: oh come in, consider this: `String s; for (int k=0; k<10; k++) { s = "string #" + k; list.add(s); }` what's wrong with it? how is it different from this case? and, yes i know i could use `String s;` inside the loop...

Answer (score 0):

You have used the same reference s after changing the value. Please create another object of ServiceSync, set the value you want and add to queue as show below.

```
BlockingQueue<ServiceSync> bq = new LinkedBlockingDeque<ServiceSync>();

ServiceSync s1 = new ServiceSync();
s1.setService(OperationsConst.CODE, commonUtil.DOWNLOAD, true, null);
bq.add(s1);

ServiceSync s2 = new ServiceSync();
s2.setService(OperationsConst.LOGIN, commonUtil.DOWNLOAD, true, null);
bq.add(s2);
```